# Django REST Framework: how to make verbose name of field differ from its field_name?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got a model with a field `tool_class`, whose verbose name is `class` and differs from name:

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    tool_class = jsonfield.JSONField(verbose_name="class")
```

The Serializer and ViewSet are just stock `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and `ModelViewSet`.

So, when I POST or PUT data to the server with a key `class`, it is recognized fine:

```
'{"class": "..."}
```

but in the response data it is called `tool_class` again:

```
{"tool_class": "..."}
```

How to make it be called `class` always?

I can't use the name `"class"` for the field name, as it is a reserved word in python, but in API it absolutely must be called `"class"`, because the API conforms to a certain open standard, which specifies this word.

Obviously, I cannot say:

```
class = CharField(source="tool_class")
```

in my `ToolSerializer`, because it's a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

---

**SIMPLE SOLUTION:**
Guys in another thread suggested a great solution. You can use `vars()` syntax to circumvent this problem. For instance, I use the following code:

```
class Tool(Document):
    vars()['class'] = mongoengine.fields.DictField(required=True)
```

Serializer creates respective field automatically. Ain't we sneaky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the metaclass for Serializers.  Here is an example of a `serializers.py` file.

The main magic is this section of the metaclass

```
# Remap fields (to use class instead of class_)
fields_ = []
for name, field in fields:
    if name.endswith('_'):
        name = name.rstrip('_')
    fields_.append((name, field))
```

This takes any field you define in the serializer that ends in an underscore (ie. `field_`) and removes the underscore from the name when it binds the `Fields` and sets the `_declared_fields` attribute on the serializer.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.fields import Field
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES

class MyMeta(serializers.SerializerMetaclass):

    @classmethod
    def _get_declared_fields(cls, bases, attrs):
        fields = [(field_name, attrs.pop(field_name))
                  for field_name, obj in list(attrs.items())
                  if isinstance(obj, Field)]
        fields.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]._creation_counter)

        # If this class is subclassing another Serializer, add that Serializer's
        # fields.  Note that we loop over the bases in *reverse*. This is necessary
        # in order to maintain the correct order of fields.
        for base in reversed(bases):
            if hasattr(base, '_declared_fields'):
                fields = list(base._declared_fields.items()) + fields

        # Remap fields (to use class instead of class_)
        fields_ = []
        for name, field in fields:
            if name.endswith('_'):
                name = name.rstrip('_')
            fields_.append((name, field))

        return OrderedDict(fields_)


class ToolSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    __metaclass__ = MyMeta

    ...
    class_ = serializers.JSONField(source='tool_class', label='class')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        ...
        instance.class_ = validated_data.get('class', instance.class_)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it should be a pull-request, modifying serializer Field to accept an extra arg. Though, it will take really much testing to debug that I can't afford writing it myself right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I tried to find a way to have a field called `class` on the serializer, using some tricks with `setattr`, but it was getting very intrusive and hacky.  The `field_name` is collected from the field at the time of binding the field to the serializer, and there is no easy place to override the behaviour of the bind.

In the end I decided it would be better and simpler just to let DRF do its thing, and add a post-processing step on the serializer:

```
class ToolSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tool

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(ToolSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data['class'] = data.pop('tool_class')
        return data
```

Note that the data structure returned by `to_representation` is an `OrderedDict`, and this disturbs the ordering slightly - the renamed key in this mapping will be removed from wherever it was at and pushed to the back.

That is unlikely to be an issue for most use-cases, so you shouldn't bother to address it if not necessary.  If you do need to preserve ordering, rebuild a new `OrderedDict` using a comprehension:

```
data = OrderedDict(
    ('class' if k == 'tool_class' else k, v) for (k, v) in data.items()
)
```

Comment: A very nice solution, wim. I guess, this is less of an evil than anything else. I'll have to re-write `to_internal_value(self, data)` in the same manner as `to_representation(self, instance)` - it's sort of a middleware.

Comment: Yep, that's the other half of it.  But it should be quite symmetric and pythonic.  It's a shame that there isn't a kwarg for the field to override the serialized name for use cases like this, when the internal name is not good.  `from` is another word that seems like it would be useful in a rest api but is clashing with a python keyword.

Comment: wim, guys in another thread suggested a great solution: use `vars()['class'] = DictField(required=True)`. It works and is very simple.